# Vue2: replace slot contents with compiled component based on regex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component `Tooltip` that adds some extra functionality.

I want to define a  wrapper component `ApplyTooltips`, which has a default `slot` and replaces all instances of `[[<any text here>]]` with `<Tooltip text="<any text here>"/>` (e.g. very similar to a Markdown parser)

I am basing my approach on this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Herteby/pL13vda2/

#### template

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="tooltip-wrapper">
      <slot>
      </slot>
      <template v-for="node, n in parsed">
       <a v-if="n % 2">{{node}}</a>
       <template v-else>{{node}}</template>
     </template>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

#### script

```js
export default {
  name: 'ApplyTooltips',
  data: () => ({
    el: null,
  }),
  computed: {
    text() {
      return this.el ? this.el.innerHTML : ''
      // return this.$slots.default[0].text
    },
    re() {
      return /\[\[(.+?)\]\]/gi // captures [[words]]
    },
    parsed() {
      return this.text.split(this.re) // every other value in this list will be a captured pattern
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.el = this.$el
    // console.log(this.$slots.default[0].elm)
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you regex is correct?

Comment: @Djip it is for for what I want it to get... according to https://regexr.com/

Comment: Ahh, missed the part where you wanted to actually capture [[ and ]]

Comment: @Djip basically capture what’s inside [[]]  and pass to a vue component